# In Sonic The Hedgehog, why wasn't there a boss for the Labyrinth Zone?

Tags: sonic-the-hedgehog

For the boss fight at the end of the fourth level of the original Sonic the Hedgehog, all you seemed to do was climb up after Robotnik. Along the way, you had to avoid the tridents coming out of the walls and the fire-spitting stone heads, and that seemed to be it.

Why wasn't there a nasty surprise waiting for you at the top? Or was the whole point to chase him through and out of the zone?

Answer (score 8):

I **can** be defeated with 8 hits, however the **real** 'boss fight' of that level is the final climb of the stage itself - you're dodging spikes & fireballs whilst trying to outrun the rising water hazard.

My presence is more of an incentive to get you to start the climb and let you know - along with the music - that this is the 'boss' section.

You can see me being defeated on Labyrinth Zone here:

Comment: Why didn't you answer in the first-person perspective?  It is you that the question was about after all. :)

Comment: @TimmyJim - Haha done, changed to be first-person :P

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe there is any indication that the boss fight was ever intended to continue at the top. So you could say that **the fight does consist of the chase itself**.

It is [actually possible](http://info.sonicretro.org/Labyrinth_Zone_boss) to defeat the boss by hitting it 8 times during the chase. As with any other boss, it yields 1000 points and causes the exploding animation to play.

The [boss for Lost Labyrinth Zone](http://info.sonicretro.org/Lost_Labyrinth_Zone_Boss) in [*Sonic the Hedgehog 4: Episode I*](http://info.sonicretro.org/Sonic_the_Hedgehog_4:_Episode_I) is based on this boss, but does end with a fight at the top as a twist.